# Independence of a linear combination of Normal Random Variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, bivariate-distributions

I would like to prove the following:

I have that $X_1, X_2$ are 2 random variables, each independently following a $N(\theta,1)$ distribution.

I firstly need to show that: 
$ X_1 - \bar{X}$  is independent of $\bar{X}$

And from this derive the distribution of $X_1$ given $\bar{X}$. 
Is there a neat/easy way of doing this?

Note in the above, $\bar{X}$ denotes the mean of the 2 random variables, and $\theta$ is unknown.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find it easier to start by showing $X_1-X_2$ and $X_1+X_2$ are independent. Then divide both by $2$

Comment: What is $X$?${}{}$

Comment: Yeah thanks Henry! I managed to do that - do you have any idea how to find the conditional distribution?